# ImageView flickers between its drawables

Tags: java, android, imageview, drawable, flicker

I have an android app with different graphical elements (ImageViews). Some ImageViews can be changed by pressing them, and then they will show another graphic. I have two systems for this, and my problem is the same for both.

In the first case I have layered two ImageViews on top of each other, and then I call each of them and set their visibility programmatically. In the second case I use the function "setImageResource" and change between different drawables.

In both cases I have the problem that the app quite often seems to "hickup" and for a split second show the wrong 'other' graphical element for each element that has a graphical alternative. It shows the wrong graphic for a split second and then jumps back to the correct graphic.

I can not find anything about this online, anyone here that recognizes this issue or have any clues as to what the problem might be?

relevant code:

```
public void setLight1(int bo) // changes a graphical element by drawable
{
    ImageView vw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.light_1);

    if (bo > 0)
        vw.setImageResource(R.drawable.lampaljus);
    else
        vw.setImageResource(R.drawable.lampaslockn);
}

private void setStickMid(int stick) // changing between two layered imageViews
{
    switch (stick)
    {
        case 1:
            ImageView vw_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stick_1_up);
            vw_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ImageView vw_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stick_1);
            vw_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    // the rest of the switch statement omitted, just more of the same
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head, try these:

1. Move all the `findViewById` code to `onCreate` of your activity, to avoid calling it multiple times.
2. How big are the assets `R.drawable.lampaljus`, `R.drawable.lampaslockn` and others, dimensions wise. Because trying to load high resolution drawables, especially PNGs, will take a lot of memory.

But I can provide a better solution, if you can post the whole `xml` and `Activity/Fragment` code.